# Cakephp 3 join satetment with where clause

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP API backend service and I want to add a new service that queries a database with the following SQL query:

```
  SELECT
  cs.number,
  cs.date,
  relation_vs_cs.relation_vs_cs_id,
  relation_vs_cs.vr_id,
  relation_vs_cs.cn_id,
  vs.vr_id,
  vs.first_name,
  vs.last_name,
  vs.document_id
FROM cs
  INNER JOIN relation_vs_cs
    ON relation_vs_cs.cn_id = cs.cn_id
  INNER JOIN vs
    ON relation_vs_cs.vr_id = vs.vr_id
WHERE vs.document_id = 'O416680668750'
```

So i do something like this in CakePhp side but it didn't work for me :

```
$options['conditions'] = array(
        'Vs.document_id' => $vrIdByDocumentId);

    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'relation_vs_cs',
            'alias' => 'Relationvscs',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Relationvscs.cn_id = Cs.cn_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'vs',
            'alias' => 'Vs',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Relationvscs.vr_id = Vs.vr_id')
        ));

    $cnTable = TableRegistry::get("Cs");
    $queryResult = $cnTable->find('all', $options)
```

When I sent a request using postman I got the following error :

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vs.document_id' in 'where clause'",
```

Could you please help Thank you in advance

Comment: check if  'Vs.document_id' is case sensitive or no.

Comment: I do but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is named `join` (singular), not `joins`, just like the corresponding query builder method.

I would also suggest that you look into setting up associations for your relationships, which would then allow you to use the `innerJoinWith()` and `leftJoinWith()` methods (among others), making your query building much easier.

Also note that you need to manually specify the fields the fields that you want to select from the joins.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/associations.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)**